# Last Row in Table Gets Removed Regardless of Button Pushed

Tags: javascript, dom

I am using JavaScript to manipulate the DOM, by creating a table. The idea is that the table generated is a list of reimbursements with buttons next to each row letting the manager approve or deny a reimbursement. The logic for generating the table in the HTML is below.

```
var r;
for (r in ajaxObject) {
    document.getElementById("reTable").innerHTML += "<tr>" +
    "<td>" + ajaxObject[r].reimbursementId + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + ajaxObject[r].amount + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + ajaxObject[r].statusName + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + ajaxObject[r].description + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + ajaxObject[r].dateSubmitted + "</td>" +
    "<td>" + ajaxObject[r].reimbursementTypeName + "</td>" +
    "<td><button id=\"accept" + r + "\">Accept</button></td>" +
    "<td><button id=\"deny" + r + "\">Deny</button></td>" +
    "</tr>";
}
r = 0;
for (r in ajaxObject) {
    var e;
    e = document.getElementById("accept" + r);
    console.log(e);
    e.onclick = function() { approveRe(ajaxObject[r].reimbursementId) };
    console.log(e.onclick);
    e = document.getElementById("deny" + r);
    console.log(e);
    e.onclick = function() { denyRe(ajaxObject[r].reimbursementId) };
    console.log(e.onclick);
}
```

Unfortunately, I am encountering a very strange problem. No matter which Approve or Deny button I push, the last row on the table gets removed. I believe that it has to do with the fact that the functions attached to the onclick events of the buttons don't actually evaluate "ajaxObject[r].reimbursementId" until they are called, by which point "r" is equal to the index of the last row in the table. I was wondering how I could get around this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use closures when you define your event handlers to fix the values of the variables that you are using from the enclosing scope.

so instead of:

```
e.onclick = function() { approveRe(ajaxObject[r].reimbursementId) };
```

You would do:

```
(function(e, id) { e.onclick = function() { approveRe(id); })(e,  ajaxObject[r].reimbursementId);
```

Alternatively, you could store the id in the element and retrieve it in a common event handler you use for all cases. You would define the elements thus:

```
<button id=\"accept" + r + "\" data-id=\"" + ajaxObject[r].reimbursementId + "\">Accept</button>
```

And then retrieve that value in the function handler:

```
function acceptHandler(e) {
   ...
}
```

and assign the event handler thus:

```
e.onclick = acceptHandler;
```

I leave the contents of the event handler as an exercise. It's not difficult - retrieve the data-id attribute's value (getAttribute) from the event target (a member of the event that is passed to the handler) and act upon it.

I'll add that this is fairly trivial in jQuery - store the id as above and use a delegated event handler on the table, select for the approve or reject buttons by class.